# vue js heading tag not working with laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, templates

here is my code for that

```
<template>
    <div>
         <h1><b>Add Employee</b></h1>
        <h2><b>Add Employee</b></h2>
        <h3><b>Add Employee</b></h3>
        <h4><b>Add Employee</b></h4>
        <h5><b>Add Employee</b></h5>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
    
}
</script>


<style scoped type="text/css">

</style>
```

this is the result

[image]

how to fix this? some explain why its happen

Comment: Remove the `<b>` tags, they don't make any sense within headings when used like that.

Comment: after remove also its look like same

Comment: Then something something is overwriting or reseting the styling.

Comment: Open inpect element and check what set of rules and where from are applied.